# Everything black except where there's a light

Tags: unity, camera, view

I have a camera in my scene with a map created at runtime:
[image]

As you can see everything can be seen. Now I want the map to be invisible (black as the background) except where there are lights. How can this be achieved in Unity3D?

Comment: you should go deep into FoW matter :)

Comment: Looks like your light isn't using shadows and your map object may not be set up to utilize them.

Comment: @Byte56 Yeah, I disabled the shadows temporarily, but I always had them enabled.

Answer (score 1):

one solution is to remove the directional light and relay only on other lights; then set [ambient light](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/13711/disable-ambient-light.html) near to dark.

Comment: I have tried to modify the ambient light with `RenderSettings.ambientLight = Color.black;` but it doesn't change at all